# PortgreSQL - Function to calculate percentages

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, percentage

In postgresql if I want percentages I just write:

```
select x / sum(x) over() ...
```

Inside a function it doesn't work since aggregate functions don't behave well.

I tried to find a solution but with no success.
This is a simple version of what I really need, but I believe the solution to this problem would surely point me in the right direction.

---

Some more details...

If I create this simple table:

```
create table ttt(v1 numeric, v2 numeric);
insert into ttt values (2,1),(5,2),(10,4);
```

If I run:

```
select v1/sum(v1) over() from ttt; --returns relative frequencies
```

I get:

```
select v1/sum(v1) over() from ttt;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.11764705882352941176
 0.29411764705882352941
 0.58823529411764705882
(3 rows)
```

Now, if I want to create a function which does the same thing, I would write:

```
create or replace function rfreq (double precision)
returns double precision
AS
'
select 
$1 / sum($1) over()
'
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

I get:

```
select rfreq(v1) from bruto;
 rfreq 
-------
     1
     1
     1
(3 rows)
```

Postgresql is not summing up inside a function.

Any suggestions?
Thank you,
Ali.

Comment: You cannot tear of some aggregation function or window function to boxed sql function. It is not supported.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But I find it strange that there is no (simple) way to build a function to calculate percentages. I'm pretty sure many people would use it. It's useful in itself and to include in more complex constructs.

Comment: @user2895901 - it could be nice, but it is not usual user request. But it is not impossible - if I understand, you would to create a custom window function. You can write own in C or you can use a PL/v8 language, that supports a custom window functions http://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/1.3.0/doc/plv8.html

Comment: Ok. That sounds like the way to go. Before asking the question, I looked at custom aggregates as a possible solution. Denis mentions that in his answer, but I guess what I really need is a custom window function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution browsing through the pl/r mailing list.

Percentages (or relative frequencies) can be calculated in postgres using the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION rel_freq(float8)
RETURNS float8 AS
$BODY$
  var <- as.vector(farg1)
  return((var/sum(var))[prownum]
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plr WINDOW;
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug your function, write the query with arbitrary parameters in a text file, and then use psql to run it:

```
\i ./myfunc.sql
```

Content of myfunc.sql would be:

```
select x / sum(y) over (...) ...
```

This will allow you to debug the function before wrapping it in a function.

When you're done and happy with the results for a few samples, copy/paste it into your function, and replace the hard-coded test values with parameters where applicable.

As to optimizing it when it has parameters, I'm not aware of any means to run explain analyze within the Postgres function, but you can get a plan which -- best I'm aware -- is the same as the function will use by preparing a statement with the same parameters. So you can explain analyze the latter instead.

---

Seeing the new details, note that if you prepare the query that you're running in function, you should always get 1 -- bar with zero.

You've an error in there, in the sense that you'd need to keep state from a call to the next first to return the expected result. Per Pavel's suggestion, you actually need a custom aggregate or a custom window function here. See the link he suggested in a comment, as well as:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html